# how to use union and intersection symbol to denote the limit

Tags: analysis

For any $x \in X$, $f_n(x) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Is this equivalent to saying $\cap_{K=1}^{\infty} \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=N}^{\infty} 
 \{x: f_n(x)\geq K\}$? Why?

My understanding: for any a positive integer K, we can find N, such that when n>N, then $f_n(x)>K$?

Comment: And what are your thoughts and attempts to solve this?

Comment: What you have is some subset of $X$. At a bare minimum you'd need to make a statement about this set in order for it to be equivalent to the statement you made about the limits of $f_n(x)$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe I made a statement.